# How do I copy the data from one table to another identical table using SQL Server r2008 and C#?

Tags: sql-server

I have both a local server and remote server that has an identically structured table in each. In the local server I have a database table which is inserted, updated regularly. There is no primary key in the table

Once a week I want to copy the data from the local table to the identical table in the remote server.

Please help me to find the solution.

Comment: Some Table structure would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you are trying to do is a Mirror database, updated weekly, if that is the case:

Using **Database Mirroring** is a best practice instead of manually doing this yourself, I suggest you read about Mirroring here:

[Database Mirroring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189852.aspx)

And afterwards follow this guide:

[Setting Up Database Mirroring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190941.aspx)

your local server should be the **principal** and your remote will be the **mirror**

**Edit:**

Just to be clear, I highly recommend this approach, it will give you benefits such as automatic failover (when your local server crashes it will use the remote one) , you can read all about the benefits in the links above so I won't carry on and on about it, just emphasize that is recommended.

Answer (score 1):

Since these are both existing tables you would do something to the extend of the following:

```
    INSERT INTO [DATABASE IP].databasename.schemaname.tablename
    (
    column1
    ,column2
    ,column3
    ,column4
    ,column5
    ,column6
    )
    select 
    column1
    ,column2
    ,column3
    ,column4
    ,column5
    ,column6
    from tablename

    where --some condition here, maybe on date?
```

For this to work you will need to make sure that you have the same login name in both databases both local and remote as well as the same password in both.

Answer (score 1):

Once Try this..

```
INSERT INTO DestinationTable (Column1,Column2,Column3)
SELECT Column1,Column2,Column3 FROM   SourceTable
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way if tables are identical is:

```
INSERT INTO table1
SELECT * FROM table2 
where <some condition>
```